# How can I call bind function inside that function?

Tags: jquery

How can I call same function inside that function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name^=prdname]").bind('keyup',function(e){
        //some code
        if($('#quick_error').val()== 0){
            $("#quick_error").val('1');
            $('input[name^=prdname]').trigger('keyup'); // Here  i want to call same function 
            return false;
        }
        // Here also a function that load a combogrid 
    });
});
```

The combogrid load the data in second time of the keypress so only, I want to try like this.

Comment: instead of `.bind` use `.on` .And check. I don't think you need to call the same  there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it a separate function and make the call to the function instead of the trigger.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name^=prdname]").bind('keyup', targetFunction);
});

function targetFunction() {
  //some code
  if ($('#quick_error').val() == 0) {
    $("#quick_error").val('1');
    targetFunction();
    return false;
  }
  //..Here also a function that load a combogrid 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a "combogrid" is, but I think this is what you're getting at...

```
var doSomething = function() {
    if($('#quick_error').val()== 0){
        $("#quick_error").val('1');
        $('input[name^=prdname]').trigger('keyup'); // Here  i want to call same function 
        doSomething();
        return false;
    }
    //..Here also a function that load a combogrid 
    doSomething();
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name^=prdname]").bind('keyup', doSomething);
});
```